# Error message "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000022)." whenever I try to open Tor

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, firefox, error

I recently downloaded Tor 4.0 on Windows 7 (64 bit) but whenever I try to start Tor browser, I get the following error message:

> firefox.exe - Application Error
>
> The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000022). Click OK
>   to close the application.

How do I get Tor to start?

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1017548 it looks like it might be an aggressive antivirus deleting some part of the tor directory.

Answer (score 1):

I was too having the same issue I found my issue was Webroot SecureAnywhere. I just had to disable it while I was using Tor.